# How do I make Windows 10 pick better video thumbnails for video files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I have numerous video clips in File Explorer which all show a black screen with a logo as their thumbnail. That's because it's the first thing shown in the video.

It would be a million times more useful if, instead, it picked a thumbnail from the middle of the video clip instead of the very first frame.

Can this be changed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have such an option, so third-party tools are required.

The article
[4 Ways To Display Thumbnail Previews For All Video Files](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/display-thumbnail-preview-video-files-windows/)
reviews four utilities that can generate video thumbnails at an offset
into the video file.

You may download and test:

- Icaros
- Media Preview
- K-Lite Codec Pack : Codec Tweak Tool
- Shark007 Codecs

As the other utilities all use software from Icaros, you might start with it.